# DBT can't reference non-ephemeral upstream model in different schema than downstream model

Tags: dbt

I'm attempting to run a downstream model which references an existing upstream table model.  This is failing because the downstream model is trying to find the upstream model in the downstream schema.

Maybe it has something to do with how environments/schemas are setup in DBT Cloud? Or maybe I'm missing something simple but for the life of me I can't find it.

I've created the simplest repro I can below.

Host: DBT Cloud

Database: Snowflake

Environment:

- upstream_model is built in the dbt cloud environment named upstream, with schema = 'upstream_model'
- downstream_model is built in the dbt cloud environment named downstream, with schema = 'downstream_model'

[DBT project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQPcn.png)

dbt_project.yml

```
name: 'repro'
config-version: 2
require-dbt-version: 0.17.2
version: '2.0.0'

...

models:
    repro:
        repro_downstream:
          +materialized: ephemeral

        repro_upstream:
          +materialized: ephemeral
```

When the upstream model materialization = 'ephemeral', it works and uses the upstream model as a CTE:
[Ephemeral materialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNCWu.png)

When the upstream model materialization = 'table', it fails because it looks in the downstream model's schema for the upstream model:
[Create table fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV2mk.png)

upstream.yml:

```
version: 2
models:
    - name: upstream_model
```

upstream_model.sql:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='**table**'
    )
}}

With model as (
    SELECT 1
)
SELECT * FROM model
```

downstream.yml:

```
version: 2

models:
    - name: downstream_model
```

downstream_model.sql:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='table'
    )
}}

With model as (
    SELECT * FROM
    {{ ref('upstream_model') }}
)

SELECT * FROM model
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for detailing the reproduction case. I haven't been able to reproduce the error you're describing, however. I don't see where you're setting the custom `schema` for `upstream_model` + `downstream_model`, and I wonder if that's the issue, since it sounds like you expect the two models to live in different schemas.

The following works fine for me:

*upstream_model.sql*:

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='table',
        schema = 'upstream'
    )
}}

With model as (
    SELECT 1
)
SELECT * FROM model
```

*downstream_model.sql*

```
{{
    config(
        materialized='table',
        schema = 'downstream'
    )
}}

With model as (
    SELECT * FROM
    {{ ref('upstream_model') }}
)

SELECT * FROM model
```

When I `dbt run`:

```
  create  table "jerco"."dbt_jcohen_upstream"."upstream_model"
  as (
    

With model as (
    SELECT 1
)
SELECT * FROM model
  );
```

```
  create  table "jerco"."dbt_jcohen_downstream"."downstream_model"
  as (
    

With model as (
    SELECT * FROM
    "jerco"."dbt_jcohen_upstream"."upstream_model"
)

SELECT * FROM model
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for investigating! Yeah I think after I consolidate to single environment I'll be able to specify schemas like you mentioned, and get the desired behavior. I just added an answer below about this.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else stumbles on this, I've just learned that I'm using DBT Cloud environments incorrectly. They don't really support models talking between environments. So I need to consolidate my models into a single environment, and then use 'custom schemas' as well as override the `generate_schema_name` macro to achieve my schema naming goals.

Custom schemas: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-schemas/